# PHPSpec - fail to run, anyone using it for php development?

Tags: php, bdd, phpspec

Searched stackoverflow for this and found no answer

Coming from Ruby On Rails and Rspec, I need a tool like rspec (easier transition). Installed it through PEAR and tried to run it but it's not working (yet)

Just wanna ask around if anyone's using it have the same problem, since it's not running at all

tried running it with an example from the manual - [http://dev.phpspec.org/manual/en/before.writing.code.specify.its.required.behaviour.html](http://dev.phpspec.org/manual/en/before.writing.code.specify.its.required.behaviour.html#id569490)

```
phpspec NewFileSystemLoggerSpec
```

returns nothing

even running

```
phpspec some_dummy_value
```

returns nothing

Answer (score 6):

Development on PHPSpec has restarted since August 2010, after a 2 years break. The code base looks more stable now. I would give another try.

The website is now located at www.phpspec.net

You can find the documentation at http://www.phpspec.net/documentation. It is basically an update of the first version.

Should you require any further assistance you can also reach the developers through their mailing list:
http://groups.google.com/group/phpspec-dev

Answer (score 0):

I also couldn't get it to run, but you can also use BDD with PHPUnit. Check the [documentation](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.3/en/behaviour-driven-development.html):

Answer (score 0):

Was really looking forward to using PHPSpec, oh I guess will check into PHPUnit

Answer (score 0):

I tried using phpspec but found it too buggy/immature. I can highly recommend [SimpleTest](http://simpletest.sourceforge.net/) for writing unittests.

Comment: Yeah, I like SimpleTest too - but I think it is a good "starter" testing suite, where PHPUnit is the evolution (supported by IDEs and more).

Comment: SimpleTest's latest release was 2008/04/08

Answer (score 0):

You can write RSpec-ish types of tests in PHPUnit, but it's hindered by a couple of things.

- PHPUnit mocks don't let you
  re-declare them so it's hard to set
  up a bunch of stubs in a before
  method and then override them as
  needed.  You can work around this by
  arranging for the stubs to be setup
  after the expectations, but it's odd.
- PHP isn't as dynamic as Ruby so you
  can't easily mock or stub out class
  methods unless you specifically
  design the class for this and even
  then it's pretty ugly.  (This may
  change with PHP 5.3's late static
  binding features).

Answer (score 0):

I have used PHPSpec succesfully but it's not actively developed now is it? It's great but don't think I would go with a stalled project. Anyway to the point I used the following setup to run the tests from the webbrowser, maybe you'll find something to help you to set it up for CLI.

PHPSpecConfiguration.php

```
$projectDir = realpath( dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..' ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$simdal_root = $projectDir . 'library';
$phpspec_root = $projectDir . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'PHPSpec';
$mockery_root = $projectDir . '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'Mockery';

$paths = array(
    'SimDAL'=>$simdal_root,
    'PHPSpec'=>$phpspec_root,
    'Mockery'=>$mockery_root
);

set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths ) . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() );

require_once 'PHPSpec.php';
require_once 'Mockery/Framework.php';

class Custom_Autoload
{
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        //$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
        //include $path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php';
        if (preg_match('/^([^ _]*)?(_[^ _]*)*$/', $class, $matches)) {
            include str_replace('_', '/', $class) . '.php';
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

}

spl_autoload_register(array('Custom_Autoload', 'autoload'));
```

and then the file that runs it all: AllSpecs.php;

```
require_once 'PHPSpecTestConfiguration.php';

$options = new stdClass();
$options->recursive = true;
$options->specdocs = true;
$options->reporter = 'html';

PHPSpec_Runner::run($options);
```

I don't like CLI testing...But this might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Hello its pretty old Q. in deed, but i think http://behat.org/ should be here. Everyone has this problem should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Note that PHPSpec is discontinued:

http://blog.astrumfutura.com/2010/05/the-mockery-php-mock-objects-made-simple/#comment-88628508

Comment: I would like to add here that PHPSpec development has been restarted. Check http://www.phpspec.net/.